# How to include a ".aco" file into an android studio project for animation?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-drawable, photoshop

I've downloaded a ".aco" file from the [dribbble](https://dribbble.com) website for payment done animation. I can't able to add it to my project. Any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: You can put that file in `src/main/res/raw` folder.

Comment: @AliAsjad Thank you so much for your reply. I've added that file to my Android project. I used **ImageView** to add ".aco" file. But it throws me an error like **File name must end with ".xml" or ".png".** Is there any other way to add it or suggest the best suitable View to access it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can't simply play .aco animation in android. You need a renderer to play that animation and i don't know about any. 

here take a look at Lottie library:

Lottie is a mobile library for Android that parses Adobe After Effects animations exported as json with Bodymovin and renders them natively on mobile!

https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android

Comment: @AliAsjad Thank you so much. It's very helpful and I tried it on my project. It's finally **WORKING FINE!!!!!!!!**.